# Removing lines from text list that don't match expression

Tags: sorting, text, filter

I've made a script that lists movies that I've processed from DVDs for Kodi into a text file.  In the example below I'd like to remove any entry that doesn't contain the year (YYYY).  What is the best way to do this?

```
300 (2006).mkv
42nd Street (1933).mkv
47 Ronin (2013).mkv
A1_t00.mkv
A1_t01.mkv
A1_t01.mkv
```

New to bash scripting and explored a couple sites with awk and sed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ {print}' list.txt >  filteredlist.txt
```

Filters text for a 4 digit number (year), excluding all the extras.